# Find monic irreducible polynomial in p-field

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $p$, $l$ be prime numbers, $n$ be positive integer. Find the number of irreducible element in $\mathbb {F_p}[x]$ with degree of $l^n$.

---

I have got the Gauss's formula $\dfrac{1}{n} *\displaystyle\sum_{d|n} µ(n/d)q^d$.
But is there any easier method working out this problem?

Thank you!

Comment: Isn't this the same question as [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2243326/monic-irreducible-polynomials-in-a-finite-field?noredirect=1&lq=1) $4$ days ago? You should not repeat the same question several times.

Comment: @DietrichBurde well, my intention was to find a solution without proving Gauss's formula...the link you referred have I already found before, but all of the 3 answers led to that formula. If you insist this is duplicated, then I will try asking it in another form...

Comment: Well, I think this will not be easier. The proof with the Moebius inversion formula is really easy.

Comment: @DietrichBurde ok, thank you for your suggestion. Close it as duplicate.